Show just one column in a pivot table excel for many dates
hope you can help me with this:
I create a pivot table with a external data source in power query, I need to show a pivot table as the following table:
PIVOT TABLE 1:
|            Column Labels ▼                                                       |



Row Labels▼
07/31/2024
08/05/2024
08/12/2024
Target
Amount Total
Delta




India
$0.7 M
$0.2 M
$0.3 M
$0.6M
$0.6M
15%


NA
$1.7 M
$0.1 M
$0.1 M
$0.5M
$0.7M
16%


LA
$0.9 M
$0.2 M
$0.4 M
$0.4M
$0.8M
12%



In the pivot table 1 we get the amount total summary by each date
but I got the following table:
PIVOT TABLE 2:
|              Column Labels ▼
|                07/31/2024        |     08/05/2024           |       08/12/2024         |



Row Labels▼
Target
Amount Total
Delta
Target
Amount Total
Delta
Target
Amount Total
Delta




India
$0.6 M
$0.3 M
13%
$0.6M
$0.2M
12%
$0.6M
$0.1M
8%


NA
$0.5 M
$0.2 M
11%
$0.5M
$0.1M
16%
$0.5M
$0.2M
14%


LA
$0.4 M
$0.1 M
11%
$0.4M
$0.1M
12%
$0.4M
$0.1M
4%



As we can see in the pivot table 2 the columns that vary are amount total and Delta. Otherwise, target it's the same for all dates in this quarter this is the column that I need to get fixed.
Also, this is my dataset what I am using:



DATE
MARKET
Quarter
Amount Total
Target Value




07/31/2024
India
FQ324
1239232
3010467


07/31/2024
NA
FQ324
3428993
832639.5


07/31/2024
LA
FQ324
9342091
1882920



I try with arrange information with pivot table formats and design options in excel as report layout options but still not getting the result.
My question is if there is any way that I can not repeat the columns for Target Amount Total and Delta for each date in columns? or any idea of how can I transform my pivot table to get the first one or just let one column of target?
Regards..

If your dataset is the last table in your question, there is no way to derive either Pivot Table 1 or Pivot table 2 from that. Please provide proper sample data and also your desired output from that data.

Also, in your Pivot Tables, it is not clear from the numbers how you are calculating the Target, Amount Total or Delta from the numbers we see. Please clarify.
